# Issues with SonarQube Version 4.3.1 - JIRA plugin issue (JIRA v6.0.7)

Tags: sonarqube

I'm able from Sonar issues view, to **link to JIRA**. The issue gets successfully created in JIRA. The JIRA description holds amongst others a link to the Sonar issue. After this there are two issues:

1. I cannot navigate from JIRA with the link provided back to Sonar. Clicking that link gives me:

> We're sorry, but something went wrong.
>   Please try back in a few minutes and contact support if the problem persists.
>   Go back to the homepage

1. The above message will also be displayed - when I try to do the same from Sonar on the specific issue on the icon at the right hand upper corner. (probably because it is the same link).

Has anyone witnessed this before?

The sonar.log shows something like this:

2014.06.19 23:10:13 ERROR [o.s.s.ui.JRubyFacade]  Fail to render: http://****:9000/issue/show/19b4e295-ac26-47d7-84f3-d60e0a49c67c?layout=false

undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
        On line #137 of app/views/issue/_issue.html.erb

```
134:          comment_html_id = "comment-#{comment.key}-#{rand(100)}" %>
135:       <div class="code-issue-comment" id="<%= comment_html_id -%>" data-comment-key="<%= comment.key -%>">
136:         <h4>
137:           <%= image_tag('reviews/comment.png') -%> &nbsp;<b><%= h( @issue_results.user(comment.userLogin()).name() ) -%></b>
138:           (<%= distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(Api::Utils.java_to_ruby_datetime(comment.createdAt)) -%>)
139:           <% if current_user && current_user.login==comment.userLogin %>
140:             &nbsp;

app/views/issue/_issue.html.erb:137
file:lib/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/jruby/java/java_ext/java.util.rb:7:in `each'
app/views/issue/_issue.html.erb:133
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2227:in `send'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:34:in `render'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:306:in `with_template'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:30:in `render'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable_partial.rb:20:in `render'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:30:in `benchmark'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable_partial.rb:19:in `render'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/template.rb:205:in `render_template'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable_partial.rb:44:in `render_partial'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/partials.rb:184:in `render_partial'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:267:in `render'
app/views/issue/_show.html.erb:25
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2227:in `send'
```

Answer (score 0):

This bug seems to come from the comment created on the issue by the JIRA plugin.
Which account has been used to click on the "Link to JIRA" button ? Was it yours ? Are you sure that this account is still existing ?

Regads

Comment: Thanks for responding! The admin account was used (for this 'test' link-to-Jira' issue). Does that matter though? Put differently: How does Sonar login user, sonarJira plugin configured user credentials relate?

Comment: It's not a problem to have used the admin account, and there's no link with the JIRA credentials. It seems that there were a strange issue when linkking the SonarQube issue to the JIRA issue. Can you try to link another SonarQube issue to JIRA ?